# Excel Horizontal

Tags: php, excel

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para que, desde el momento que se descarga el Excel y lo abro la orientación de la página sea horizontal?.

He intentado poner esto desde el inicio del código, pero no funciona.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setHorizontalCentered(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setVerticalCentered(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código para cambiar la orientación de la hoja:

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setHorizontalCentered(true);
```

o

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation("landscape");
```

Para ver la orientación de la hoja del archivo Excel, debes ir a la ***Vista***. Ahí debes seleccionar ***diseño de pagina*** o la **Vista Saltos de pagina**.

Si la vista es normal, no verás cambios.

También puedes ver los cambios, si intentas imprimir la hoja.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es justamente establecer la orientación de la página. Con el código que muestras estas estableciendo algunas opciones de impresión. La orientación de la página en *horizontal* sería algo como:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Para *vertical*, en cambio utilizas `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`